# How to get the ListAdapter and update the shown list on an Android Activity Screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listadapter

I am setting up a view of a list. I got the list from a remote server call in a AsynchTask call and now in the `onPostExecute` method I am trying to update the list view with the items I got from the db.

I have some code like this:

```
ListAdapter l = getListAdapter();
```

But the ListAdapter does not have the `notifyDataSetChanged();` that I need to call to change the original list that was set.

How do I update my list that is shown to the screen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which adapter you actually used and which class it extends you may coerce your adapter like this:

```
((ArrayAdapter<MyClass>) yourListView
        .getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is required since only certain adapters have this method.

While I have defined my own adapter like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends
    ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {...
```